# I want to format my expss-table and include specific rows based on values

Tags: r, expss

I've been looking into doin tables with the expss package. I have two questions. The first is that I'm wondering if it's possible to format the table so that the mean for each variable comes after the "total_statistics". The second question is if it's possible to format the output table by including new rows that are based on the values from the output table. I have been looking at the manual for expss and also tried a lot of different coding (to much to show here) and right now it feels that I'm bashing my head to a wall. Greatful for answers!

The code I have right now looks like this:

> 

```
test_table <- mtcars %>%
+   tab_cells(cyl, vs) %>%
+   tab_cols(
+     total(label = "All")) %>%
+   tab_stat_cpct(
+     total_row_position = "below",
+     total_statistic = c("u_cpct", "u_cases"),
+     total_label = c("percent", "unweighted answers")
+   ) %>%
+   tab_stat_mean(label = "Mean") %>%
+   tab_pivot(stat_label = "inside") 
> 
> test_table
```

With the ouput:

```
 |                     |                     |   All |
 | ------------------- | ------------------- | ----- |
 | Number of cylinders |                   4 |  34.4 |
 |                     |                   6 |  21.9 |
 |                     |                   8 |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 |              Engine |            V-engine |  56.2 |
 |                     |     Straight engine |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 | Number of cylinders |                Mean |   6.2 |
 |              Engine |                Mean |   0.4 |
```

As you can see, the mean for each variable ends up at the bottom. I want it after each variable. Like this:

```
 |                     |                     |   All |
 | ------------------- | ------------------- | ----- |
 | Number of cylinders |                   4 |  34.4 |
 |                     |                   6 |  21.9 |
 |                     |                   8 |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 |                     |                Mean |   6.2 |
 |              Engine |            V-engine |  56.2 |
 |                     |     Straight engine |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 |                     |                Mean |   0.4 |
```

I also wonder if it's possible to add a new row after each variable that sums upp the totalt if criteras are meet. For example with the mtcars data, I want a row that sums upp the totalt for *number of cylinders* if it has 6 or more cylinders. Something like this:

```
|                     |                     |   All |
 | ------------------- | ------------------- | ----- |
 | Number of cylinders |                   4 |  34.4 |
 |                     |                   6 |  21.9 |
 |                     |                   8 |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 |                     |                Mean |   6.2 |
 |                     | Top2 (6 or more cyl)|  65.7 |
 |              Engine |            V-engine |  56.2 |
 |                     |     Straight engine |  43.8 |
 |                     |            #percent | 100.0 |
 |                     | #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
 |                     |                Mean |   0.4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For mean after each variable you need to reorganize your "tab_*" code. See below.
2. For subtotal there are special functions `net` and `subtotal` but they can't hide some categories. So we need to remove them manually from the final table:

```
library(expss)
test_table = mtcars %>%
    tab_total_statistic("u_cpct", "u_cases") %>% 
    tab_total_row_position("below") %>% 
    tab_total_label("percent", "unweighted answers") %>% 
    tab_cols(total(label = "All")) %>%
    tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_stat_mean(label = "Mean") %>%
    tab_cells(
        net(cyl, "cyl|Top2 (6 or more cyl)" = greater_or_equal(6), "TO DELETE" = other)
    ) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = "none") %>% 
    tab_cells(vs) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_stat_mean(label = "Mean") %>%
    tab_pivot(stat_label = "inside") %>% 
    subset(row_labels != "TO DELETE")

test_table
# |     |                      |   All |
# | --- | -------------------- | ----- |
# | cyl |                    4 |  34.4 |
# |     |                    6 |  21.9 |
# |     |                    8 |  43.8 |
# |     |             #percent | 100.0 |
# |     |  #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
# |     |                 Mean |   6.2 |
# |     | Top2 (6 or more cyl) |  65.6 |
# |  vs |                    0 |  56.2 |
# |     |                    1 |  43.8 |
# |     |             #percent | 100.0 |
# |     |  #unweighted answers |  32.0 |
# |     |                 Mean |   0.4 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try the code as soon as I come home from my vacation :)